# Angular Js On form submit send json string to server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, json

I create a factory to manage json data

```
angular
.module("autoQuote")
.controller(dtoController)
.factory(prepareDtoFactory);

function dtoController(prepareDtoFactory){
     prepareDtoFactory.rc1Step1DTO(); //call function from your service, and do something with it
}

dtoController.$inject = ['prepareDtoFactory'];

function prepareDtoFactory(){

    var prepareAutoQuoteDTO = {
        postAutoQuoteObj         : $.getAutoQuoteObject(),  
        initializeDriverObj: function(){
            var driverLocObj           = new Driver();
            driverLocObj.PersonInfo    = new PersonInfo();
            driverLocObj.DriverLicense = new DriverLicense();
            driverLocObj.Incident      = new Incident();
            return driverLocObj;
       },
       initializeAppInfo: function(){
           var appInfoLocObj           = new ApplicationInfo();
           appInfoLocObj.Discount      = new Discount();
           return appInfoLocObj;
       },
       /*
       * Initialize Vehicle object for autoQuoteDTO.js
       */
       initializeVehicleObj: function(){
           var vehicleLocObj = new Vehicle();
           return vehicleLocObj;
       },
       /*
       * store session info
       */
       rc1Step1DTO: function(){

            var emailId = $('#save_quote_email').val();
            if (typeof emailId  !== "undefined" && emailId && emailId != '' && emailId != 'Email Address'){
                var email           = new Email();
                email.EmailTypeCd   = 'PRIMARY';
                email.EmailAddress  = emailId;
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo =     this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo || new Contact();
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails = [];
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails.push(email);
            }
        }
    };
    return prepareAutoQuoteDTO;
}
```

view - form

```
 <div ui-view>
<form name="DTOstep1" >
  <input type="text" name="save_quote_email" id="save_quote_email" />
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
 </div>
```

On this form submit I want to call dtoController to send json data to server.
I am not getting how to write function to that will read json data and send this data to server(API call). how to call an API.
API is in php that will read post data.

Complete code is here http://plnkr.co/edit/VJKrDRMJY3Q73bsCgVwX?p=preview.

Please suggest me if my development approach is require some change.

Comment: Use `$http` to send. Other than that this question is far too vague

Comment: thanks. I am getting confused where to write function to do this http call. Ca you get me sample code with my plunker.

Comment: Use `ng-submit`...see docs

Comment: Error [$injector:pget] Provider 'function prepareDtoFactory()' must define $get factory method.